# Can't display Wordpress categories which are assigned to a private post

Tags: wordpress

I have a single post which is private. I have assigned a category to it, but now I'm not able to display categories using the `get_categories()` function. 
The category page on wp-admin shows that no post is assigned to the category. 
How do I get around this?

Comment: You can't display any categories? Or just this one? Make your question more clear!

Comment: just want to display categories which is assigned to private post.

Answer (score 1):

I found this code on [WordPress Forum](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-get-the-lists-of-categories-used-in-custom-post-type) that does very similar.

I modified it to your needs:

```
  global $wpdb;
  $post_type_ids = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'private'");

  if($post_type_ids){
    $post_type_cats = wp_get_object_terms( $post_type_ids, 'category',array('fields' => 'ids') );
    if($post_type_cats){
      $post_type_cats = array_unique($post_type_cats);
      $post_type_cats = implode(',',$post_type_cats);
      $cats=get_categories('include='.$post_type_cats);
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you want to show categories of the current post, just replace above $post_type_ids line with $post_type_ids =  the_ID();

Comment: Thats great. If you found the answer helpful, please take a moment and accept it by clicking on the large checkbox on the left side of this answer.